# What sort of "recovery" do genesen or erholen represent?

Tags: verb, meaning

I’ve recently come across the verb *genesen* and got confused. I had been using *erholen*, but now I have the suspicion it’s something to do with relaxing? and not actually recovering from an illness?

So if my relative was sick and I wanted to ask if he has recovered yet, would I say:

> Ist er schon genesen?
>   Ich hoffe, dass er genesen ist!

but then how would I use *erholen*?

and is *genesen* also for something very serious like recovering from cancer? It feels like its more for say *eine Erkältung*.

Comment: As an alternative you could also ask: "Ist er wieder gesund?" (Is he healthy/well again). "Ich hoffe er ist bald gesund" (I hope he is healthy soon)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Wer sich von einer Krankheit vollständig erholt hat, ist genesen.

*Genesen* (Genesung) umfasst den `Prozess` vom Zustand `krank` hin zum Zustand `gesund`.
*Erholen* (Erholung) ist eine unspezifische Verbesserung des Befindens.

Answer (score 6):

"Genesen" verwendet man nur bei Krankheiten.

"Erholen" kann man sich auch von einem Schreck, einem anstrengenden Fussballspiel oder vom Arbeitsalltag.

Answer (score 5):

If you refer to an illness, *erholen* means *feeling better* or *getting better. Genesen* is more like *being cured, really being back to health.*

*Erholen* also means *relaxing,* but in different contexts.

Answer (score 0):

> and is genesen also for something very serious like recovering from cancer?

**Not also, but rather.**

In contrast **erholen** you would use if somebody recovered from something that physically compromised him. If you have a slight cold that is hardly noticable, you'd be probably rather asked

> Bist du wieder gesund?

or (emphasizing absence of physical impairment due to the illness)

> Bist du wieder fit?