# Wie sagt man "to recover from a sickness"?

Tags: translation, word-choice, difference

Ich bin mir unsicher, wie ich sagen kann:

> I am recovering from a cold.

In einem Online-Wörterbuch steht, dass es zwei Verben gibt, die in diesem Zusammenhang passen, nämlich:

> sich erholen
>   genesen.

Kann ich die beiden in diesem Kontext verwenden? Gibt es einen großen Unterschied dazwischen? Wenn es keinen gibt, sind dann also die folgenden Sätze richtig?

> Ich erhole mich von einer Erkältung.
>   Ich genese (mich?) von einer Erkältung.

Und welches Verb verwendet man öfters?

Comment: See also https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/10310/what-sort-of-recovery-do-genesen-or-erholen-represent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Erholen* muss nicht unbedingt etwas mit einer Krankheit zu tun haben. Man kann sich auch von der Arbeit *erholen*.

Normalerweise sagt man

> Ich erhole mich von einer Erkältung.

*Genesen* oder *die Genesung* klingt etwas streng, als würde es ein Arzt sagen.

> Die Genesung dauert vermutlich fünf Wochen.

Man sagt aber auch

> Gute Besserung/Genesung.

Eine weitere Möglichkeit ist *etwas auskurieren*, aber das ist etwas schwieriger zu benutzen.

Zum Beispiel:

> Ich kuriere zurzeit eine Erkältung aus.
>   Er muss eine Erkältung auskurieren.