# How to ask a friend if they feel better after being sick?

Tags: english-to-german

My friend has been feeling a bit unwell since last week. It has been about 3 days since the last time we talked.
The first time I was informed about the situation, my reaction was: "Ich hoffe, dass es dir bald wieder gut geht".

Now after three days, I would like to ask a follow-up question to know if the situation has gotten better, but I could not find a correct way of formulating it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Related [question1](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/10310/1696)  and [question2](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/22638/1696).

Answer (score 3):

I think, "Geht es dir (inzwischen wieder) besser?" would work. As well as "Bist du wieder gesund?" If you want to be more specific (for example concerning headache) you could use "Wie geht es deinen Kopfschmerzen?" However I am not sure whether that is more colloquial language.

Comment: The last one ("Wie geht es deinen Kopfschmerzen?") only works if the friend understands jokes. Because if the answer is "Den Kopfschmerzen geht es gut", that's unlikely what one wants.

Comment: @PMF Looks like one of the many examples of idioms that start out as a joke, and after a while people used it so often that they just forget that it wasn't meant litarally in the beginning.

Comment: A simple "Wie geht es dir heute?" would also work. With adding "heute" it would direct the focus from the meaningless greeting to a honest question and implicate that the person was not so well before.